# How to maintain dual source control or repositories with one visual studio project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, azure-devops

I am the sole developer on a project for my client.

Clients wants me to checkin (process/formality) the source to his repository in `Bitbucket.com`. However, I use the `TFS VisualStudioOnline.com`

Bitbucket: His motivation was to look and have an internal deposit of my regular code for weekly draws.

VisualstudioOnline.com: For me, I use TFS extensively and need to maintain my checkins here, with my code and builds.

Questions: **How can I maintain/add two source controls on one project? (where one project is mostly a readonly/view only checkin)**

Comment: is the VSTS repo a git based one, or TFVC?

Comment: And what is the type of your client's repo, Git or Mercurial?

Comment: Hi I am curious too, how would you do this/dual scenario if you have *both* VisualStudioOnline TFS bindings

Answer (score 1):

That's very easy: just add an additional remote to the Git repository, something like

```
git remote add customer http://bibucket.com/whatver
```

If you want to "filter" what you push to customer, say have one commit instead of three, then things starts to complicate a bit.